# Multistage Docker build with lxml

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, lxml

I'm trying to build a smaller image for an app that has a dependency on the `lxml` package for `bs4` (my `Pipfile` only has those two packages).

Here's what I've got:

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine as build

COPY src/ /app/src/
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /app/

# for python lxml
RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
    g++ \
    python3-dev \
    libxml2 \
    libxml2-dev && \
    apk add libxslt-dev && \
    apk del .build-deps

RUN pip install pipenv==2020.6.2

WORKDIR /app

ENV PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT 1
RUN pipenv install --deploy


FROM python:3.8-alpine as run
COPY --from=build /app /app/
WORKDIR /app
RUN addgroup -S app && adduser -S -G app app 
USER app
CMD .venv/bin/python src/main.py
```

The build works, but when I try to run my app in the second stage image I get:

```
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?
```

If I make this a single stage build and run the app in the first stage, everything works fine, implying that the `lxml` package gets properly built and installed during the first stage, but is not copied over to the second stage.

**How can I move over my `lxml` package to the second stage?**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `libxml2` try with `lxml`, you may need to make some changes in your application's python files. Beautiful Soup also supports it, official documentation: [Installing a parser](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser).